# How to scan a directory for assemblies and load them?

Tags: c#, dllimport, dynamic-loading

I would like to scan a directory for any assemblies that are not already referenced in the project then load all instances of a class that implements IMyInterface.

I know that the [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile(VS.71,loband).aspx) method can help me out here but how do I determine if the assembly that I am loading was already referenced statically?  I do not want to load any assemblies twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AppDomain.GetAssemblies` to see which are already loaded.